# Help correcting gimp font size

Tags: arch-linux, gimp, high-dpi

I'm using X1C gen 7 4k, xfce, lightdm, uefi & grub install

> Arch wiki wrote:
>
> Gimp 2.10 To fix toolbar icon sizes, update
> Preferences->Interface->Icon Theme->Custom icon size to huge or other
> value. If menu fonts are still too small you can update an existing
> theme by copying it from /usr/share/gimp/2.0/themes into
> ~/.config/GIMP/2.10/themes/ and changing gtk-font-name and font_name
> in gtkrc into something bigger like Sans 30. Then select the new theme
> from Preferences > Interface > Theme. When copying make sure to rename
> the new directory into something different from the original name
> (example Dark > DarkHighDPI). You can also try using gimp-hidpi
> (installation instructions are outdated and refer to version 2.8, in
> Gimp 2.10 the theme should be installed into
> ~/.config/GIMP/2.10/themes/)

I've done all the above to no avail, nothing changed. I'm not sure where to go from here.

What I did exactly was:

1. changed the settings in preferences and made the icon size huge.

   2. `mkdir ~/.config/GIMP/2.10/themes/DarkHighDPI`
2. from within

   /usr/share/gimp/2.0/themes/Dark

I

```
sudo cp -r gtkrc ui ~/.config/GIMP/2.10/themes/DarkHighDPI
```

4. I edited the gtkrc file with sans 30 for both the gtk-font-name and font_name
5. Then from within the gimp program again I changed the theme settings to DarkHighDPI
6. rebooted my laptop started gimp, still no change.
7. I restored a timeshift backup to revert all changes I had made.

Answer (score 1):

Tested with GIMP 2.8.22 on Ubuntu 18.04 (XFCE), so I don't know if this works with your version on Arch.

1. Copy the default theme to `~/.gimp-2.8/themes/HiDPI`:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.gimp-2.8/themes
   cp -a /usr/share/gimp/2.0/themes/Default ~/.gimp-2.8/themes/HiDPI
   ```
2. Edit `~/.gimp-2.8/themes/HiDPI/gtkrc` and add a line `font_name = "sans 30"` (copied and adjusted from the "Small" theme):

   ```
   ...
     stock["gtk-dialog-warning"] =
       {
         { "images/stock-warning-64.png", *, *, "gtk-dialog" }
       }

     ### this line was added ###
     font_name = "sans 30"

     GtkPaned::handle-size             = 6
     GimpDockWindow::default-height    = 300
     GimpDock::font-scale              = 0.8333
     GimpMenuDock::minimal-width       = 200
   ...
   ```
3. Open GIMP, go to `Edit -> Preferences -> Theme` and select theme `HiDPI`.

   Result:
   [image: GIMP menu Sans 30]

Comment: On the arch wiki it says [quote=wiki]You can also try using gimp-hidpi (installation instructions are outdated and refer to version 2.8, in Gimp 2.10 the theme should be installed into ~/.config/GIMP/2.10/themes/)[/quote]

Comment: So I'm pretty sure it won't work for me. I will try again tomorrow using the mkdir cmd with the -p flag and the cp with the -a flag. lol i'm very new to linux I don't really know/understand those flags yet. I think the -p flag makes parent directories, but I don't know what that means.Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Yep, haven't tried gimp-hidpi. And my theme wasn't detected in `~/.config/GIMP/2.10/themes/`, I guess it was the wrong config directory for my GIMP version since my `~/.gimp-2.8` contains lots of files and directories. Use `~/.config/GIMP/2.10/themes/` instead if that works for you. The `-p` flag creates both directories `~/.gimp-2.8` and `~/.gimp-2.8/themes` if they don't already exist and `cp -a` copies recursively preserving attributes and links (archive mode).

Comment: Thanks about the flags. thats the issue it doesn't seem to be working for me. I did think that cp -r was to copy recursively though

Comment: I could be doing it wrong, not sure. I did it the way I mentioned in my post. I didn't know how to copy the whole directory and change the name at the other end. Thats why I made the directory first and then went into the default theme directory and copied from there

Answer (score 1):

I apologise for wasting your time. The correct way of doing it is what I did in the beginning but.....when editing the sans 30 the line has to be uncommented.

bad error on my part.